# Rails 4 has_one - always overwrites first record

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, has-one

First I thought this is a validation issue but then realized that every time a record gets saved it just overwrites the first record.

List.rb

```
belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => "user_id"
```

In my modell I have:

```
create_table "lists", force: :cascade do |t|
t.text     "pont12"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.integer  "user_id"
end
```

User.rb

```
has_one :list, dependent: :destroy
```

ListsController

```
def new
@list = current_user.build_list
...
def create
@list = current_user.build_list(list_params)
....
```

In the logs after I "successfully" create a list on the frontend:

```
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
List Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "lists".* FROM "lists" WHERE "lists"."user_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 4]]
(0.3ms)  begin transaction
SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "lists" ("pont12", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["pont12", "the list..."], ["user_id", 4], ["created_at", "2015-03-06 10:03:45.368204"], ["updated_at", "2015-03-06 10:03:45.368204"]]
(11.1ms)  commit transaction
```

And that just overwrote the first record.

ps: new to Rails ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: The foreign_key needs to be on the has_one not on the belongs_to line int he model.